# How to delete a private Amazon Seller Central app or at least change the client secret?

Tags: amazon-mws, amazonsellercentral, amazon-selling-partner-api

I'm having the most bizarre problem, which I thought would be quite simple to fix. I helped a client set up a connection to the Amazon Selling Partner API by creating a private app in Seller Central:

1. `Settings > User Permissions > Visit Developer Credentials`
2. New app client
3. Get LWA credentials (client secret and client id)
4. Self authorize the app to obtain a refresh token

I've been using this successfully to pull Amazon SP API data for this client, but now the client wants to ensure we don't keep having access to their data and would like to either **remove the app and create a new one** or at least **invalidate existing refresh tokens and/or client secrets** and generate new ones. It's quite easy to create a new refresh token, but this doesn't invalidate the existing ones.

I've tried everything, including unticking all the boxes that grant you access to various scopes and putting in a random IAM ARN, but you have to leave at least one box ticked and the ARN has to match an existing one. Getting a non-technical client to create a new IAM ARN just for this doesn't make us look great, and I'm sure there has to be a way to revoke those credentials - what would happen if they became compromised for some reason?